# Cylindrical coordinates - Orthonormal system

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems

Using cylindrical coordinates and the orthonormal system of vectors $\overrightarrow{e}_r, \overrightarrow{e}_{\theta}, \overrightarrow{e}_z$

- describe each of the $\overrightarrow{e}_r$, $\overrightarrow{e}_{\theta}$ and $\overrightarrow{e}_z$ as a function of $\overrightarrow{i}, \overrightarrow{j}, \overrightarrow{k}$ and $(x, y, z)$ and
- calculate $\overrightarrow{e}_{\theta} \times \overrightarrow{j}$ with two ways: analytically, using (1), and geometrically.

Could you give me some hints how I could do that??

Comment: how can we show it geometrically?? @Surb

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions (the link was wrong). For the geometric interpretation, have you tried to draw it?